# Time to event analsis plot with different colors before time 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the next idea that I do not know how to complete.
I have tried something

I have generated the next plot based on the next dataset:
structure(list(type = c("dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic",
"dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic",
"dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic",
"dynamic", "dynamic"), term = c("ATT(-4)", "ATT(-3)", "ATT(-2)",
"ATT(-1)", "ATT(0)", "ATT(1)", "ATT(2)", "ATT(3)", "ATT(4)",
"ATT(-4)", "ATT(-3)", "ATT(-2)", "ATT(-1)", "ATT(0)", "ATT(1)",
"ATT(2)", "ATT(3)", "ATT(4)"), event.time = c(-4, -3, -2, -1,
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4), estimate = c(5.88828038188665,
-3.22694176637139, 0.967347560219703, -1.9679508215827, -4.70675136419725,
-5.37165592730874, -7.24883696006244, -7.94467247403531, -7.67190853763052,
3.37540032210714, -3.33780093594465, 0.233751496599906, -1.42664058559723,
-2.48408395534435, -3.23755224089758, -3.33783114439767, -3.63353958384532,
-7.30041662955429), std.error = c(2.55395008683573, 2.26046636148949,
1.74955830708941, 1.08112117765052, 0.922584951658311, 1.34012711238458,
1.69066513986662, 1.91973713966613, 1.99152159186523, 2.62835657174871,
1.98059545348791, 1.28821045970996, 0.86608051177184, 0.727282651139265,
0.920421670144516, 1.43731341321305, 1.4045452854311, 1.60261820603537
), conf.low = c(-1.02147700372138, -9.34267371302517, -3.76611355802043,
-4.8929433970106, -7.20282136040852, -8.99739366595254, -11.8229615668817,
-13.138555450687, -13.0600056264965, -3.9128354228653, -8.82984365784844,
-3.33835954054865, -3.82821692107894, -4.50078422794279, -5.7898125349913,
-7.32339349446271, -7.52823837195565, -11.7443567784358), conf.high = c(12.7980377674947,
2.88879018028239, 5.70080867845984, 0.957041753845189, -2.21068136798598,
-1.74591818866494, -2.67471235324322, -2.75078949738366, -2.28381144876454,
10.6636360670796, 2.15424178595914, 3.80586253374846, 0.974935749884492,
-0.467383682745911, -0.685291946803871, 0.647731205667375, 0.261159204265009,
-2.85647648067279), point.conf.low = c(0.882630193375675, -7.65737442315508,
-2.46172371052841, -4.08690939270125, -6.51498464212617, -7.99825680228818,
-10.5624797441184, -11.7072881275649, -11.5752191321202, -1.77608389704948,
-7.21969669272473, -2.2910946089394, -3.12412719638205, -3.90953175815812,
-5.04154556497104, -6.15491366879157, -6.38639775794581, -10.4414905943518
), point.conf.high = c(10.8939305703976, 1.2034908904123, 4.39641883096782,
0.151007749535846, -2.89851808626834, -2.7450550523293, -3.9351941760065,
-4.18205682050575, -3.76859794314079, 8.52688454126377, 0.544094820835426,
2.75859760213921, 0.270846025187598, -1.05863615253058, -1.43355891682413,
-0.520748620003761, -0.880681409744823, -4.15934266475677), gender = c("Male",
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male",
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female",
"Female", "Female")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")

Then I have generated this plot that is a event study where I compare by gender some quantities of interest.  First of all I am getting this warning that I would like to quit.
What I would like to include is in order to observe the evolution of the amount of interest over time, I would like to differentiate the color of the lines. More precisely I would like to have before the time 0 all the lines with a blue color not so dark and after zero a darker blue. The same with the red lines.

```
   boris|>ggplot(aes(x=event.time,y=estimate,color=gender))+
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(w=0.35))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=conf.low,ymax=conf.high,alpha=prepost),position=position_dodge(w=0.25))+
   scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue1"))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype = "longdash" )+ 
  scale_x_discrete(name ="event.time", limits=c(-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4))
```

Basically, I created a new column that consider if the event.time is lower than 0 then the respective cell will be equals 0.6 otherwise 0.8

```
boris<-boris|>mutate(prepost=ifelse(event.time<=0,0.6,0.8))
```

However, the plot is not working as I want. It is almost done but I do not know what is the problem.

[image]